# How do I set Firefox to use a custom theme for all new users?

Tags: firefox, themes

What I do know about applying the same settings for applications to all new users is either defining a schema or override file in `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas` or copying the folder/file to `/etc/skel`. When a new user is created, that user is automatically given the gsettings/config file.

So, my question is:

- How do I apply a theme to Firefox and get this to apply to all users?
- Does Firefox use *gsettings* type settings? And if so, which ones?
- Does Firefox use config files (e.g. in `~/.config`)? If so which ones?

I happen to be using either *Gnome Shell* or *Unity*, but I think the answer will apply to any desktop environment.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Step 1: Download the theme file

Go to [Firefox Themes website](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/themes/) and download the xpi file of your favorite theme, say [Arc Theme](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/arc-theme/).

[image: Download Arc Theme]

### Step 2: Install the theme for all users

Open the downloaded theme file with *Archive Manager*.

[image: Open with Archive Manager]

You'll see an `install.rdf` file inside. Open it too and copy the ID between the first `<em:id>` and`</em:id>` you find, which in *Arc Theme*'s case is `{52c2877e-44e1-11e5-8874-a62d1d5d46B0}`. Note the theme's internal name too, you'll need it later.

[image: Theme ID and Name]

Rename the theme's xpi file with the ID you just copied. Then place the renamed xpi file in `/usr/lib/firefox-addons/extensions/`. To do so, open the *Terminal* and run this command:

```
pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY nautilus /usr/lib/firefox-addons/extensions/
```

and copy the xpi file (`{52c2877e-44e1-11e5-8874-a62d1d5d46B0}.xpi` in *Arc Theme*'s case) to the *File Manager* window that opens up.

[image: Install theme to extensions folder]

### Step 3: Set the theme as default

Create a `theme.js` file (or a `.js` file with any name you like) in `/usr/lib/firefox/browser/defaults/preferences/`. To do so, open the *Terminal* and run this command:

```
pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY gedit /usr/lib/firefox/browser/defaults/preferences/theme.js
```

When the preferences file gets opened in *Text Editor*, copy and paste this into it:

```
pref("general.skins.selectedSkin", "arc-theme");
```

But, don't forget to replace `arc-theme` with the theme's internal name you saw in `install.rdf`!

Okay, that's all. Firefox is now set to use your favorite theme by default! Tested and verified on **Ubuntu 14.04LTS** with **Firefox 45**.

[image: Firefox Arc Themed]

---

### Background

[Solus Project](https://solus-project.com) uses Firefox as it's default browser, but with it's theme set to *Arc Darker* 'out of box'. So, I poked around their [firefox](https://git.solus-project.com/packages/firefox/tree/files/prefs.js) and [arc-firefox-theme](https://packages.solus-project.com/shannon/a/arc-firefox-theme/) packages, found out how it works and then reproduced the method on Ubuntu.

Comment: Nice well written answer.Very useful

Comment: Why use `pkexec` when you can use `sudo`

Comment: Using `sudo` for GUI applications like Nautilus or Gedit is a bad idea @SuiciDoga, but you could simply use `gksudo nautilus /path/to/directory` and `gksudo gedit /path/to/file` - that's what I personally use.

Comment: @ByteCommander Why is it?

Comment: @SuiciDoga Read this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-user-should-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-application

Comment: @ByteCommander  `gksudo` got deprecated and is no longer preinstalled in Ubuntu. Got removed from default installation image by 14.04LTS or so. That's why I used `pkexec` instead. Yeah, the commands're pretty big when compared to `gksudo`, but I think **Ubuntu 16.04LTS** may have updated [Polkit files for gedit and nautilus](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/03/how-to-run-gedit-and-nautilus-as-root.html). I'll check if it can be run by simply `pkexec nautilus` without the environmental variables and update the answer when 16.04LTS is out. 

Comment: @HEXcube Aha. Well, I still always install the `gksu` package on every system. I don't see why it should be deprecated - at least as long as there's no equally simple alternative.

Comment: Also @ByteCommander I can find posts *suggesting* `gksudo` is deprecated, but cannot find a reliable source. The fact that it is not installed by default on Ubuntu does not mean it shouldn't be. Do you have a reliable source, other then "I think...."?